# Javascript / AngularJS - Accessing the property of an object during initialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to access the total property and change the noun property into "items" if the total is greater than 1. and also update the sentence property using the total and noun property.

Here's my code:

```
$scope.itemCounter = {
            total: 0,
            noun: $scope.itemCounter.total <= 1 ? "item" : "items",
            sentence: $scope.itemCounter.total+" "+$scope.itemCounter.noun+" remaining"
        };
```

**But it gives me this error:**

```
Cannot read property 'total' of undefined
```

**The expected output should be:**

```
$scope.itemCounter.sentence = "0 item remaining";
```

Is it because that the $scope.itemCounter is not yet initialized ? can anyone provide me a better approach if this one is not possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
$scope.itemCounter = {
            total: 0,
            noun: $scope.itemCounter.total <= 1 ? "item" : "items",
            get sentence(){ 
           return $scope.itemCounter.total+" "+$scope.itemCounter.noun+" remaining"
         }
  };
```